# Add dates ranges to a table for individual values using a cursor

Tags: t-sql

I have a calendar table called CalendarInformation that gives me a list of dates from 2015 to 2025. This table has a column called BusinessDay that shows what dates are weekends or holidays. I have another table called OpenProblemtimeDiffTable with a column called number for my problem number and a date for when the problem was opened called ProblemNew and another date for the current column called Now. What I want to do is for each problem number grab its date ranges and find the dates between and then sum them up to give me the number of business days. Then I want to insert these values in another table with the problem number associated with the business day.

Thanks in advance and I hope I was clear.

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE ProblemsMoreThan7BusinessDays


DECLARE @date AS date

DECLARE @businessday AS INT
DECLARE @Startdate as DATE, @EndDate as DATE

DECLARE CONTACT_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 

SELECT date, businessday
FROM CalendarInformation


OPEN contact_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM Contact_cursor INTO @date, @businessday

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0)

BEGIN

SELECT @enddate= now FROM  OpenProblemtimeDiffTable 

SELECT @Startdate= problemnew FROM  OpenProblemtimeDiffTable 

SET @Date=@Startdate

PRINT @enddate
PRINT @startdate

SELECT @businessday=  SUM (businessday) FROM CalendarInformation WHERE date > @startdate AND date <= @Enddate

INSERT INTO ProblemsMoreThan7BusinessDays (businessdays, number)
SELECT @businessday, number
FROM OpenProblemtimeDiffTable

FETCH NEXT FROM CONTACT_CURSOR INTO @date, @businessday

END 
CLOSE CONTACT_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE CONTACT_CURSOR
```

I tried this code using a cursor and I'm close, but I cannot get the date ranges to change for each row.

So if I have a problemnumber with date ranges between 02-07-2018 and 05-20-2019, I would want in my new table the sum of business days from the calendar along with the problem number. So my output would be column number PROB0421 businessdays (with the correct sum). Then the next problem PRB0422 with date ranges of 11-6-18 to 5-20-19. So my output would be PROB0422 with the correct sum of business days.

Comment: it will help a lot to see the structure of your two tables. i had thought that your OpenProblemtimeDiffTable table would have row for each problem, but you populate your variables from it without a "where" clause. Does this table only have one problem in it at a time? I dont think you need to use a cursor here, this should be doable in a single "insert...select"

Comment: Hi Jamie, No the OpenProblemtimeDiffTable has the number, problemnew, and now columns. With each problem number in it. The calendar information table has every date and businessday column. Is this the information you need to help? Thanks so much.

Comment: Got it. That's what I had assumed, but wasn't sure. I added an answer, but it takes a different path than what you had with use of a cursor. If you must continue with the cursor, then it seems you have a problem with your code where you set @enddate= now and @Startdate= problemnew from OpenProblemtimeDiffTable . You do not have a "where" clause to tell it which problem you want data for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing this in with a `cursor`, you should approach this in a set based manner.  That you already have a calendar table makes this a lot easier.  The basic approach is to `select` from your data table and `join` into your calendar table to return all the rows in the calendar table that sit within your date range.  From here you can then aggregate as you require.

This would look something like the below, though apply it to your situation and adjust as required:

```
select p.ProblemNow
      ,p.Now
      ,sum(c.BusinessDay) as BusinessDays
from dbo.Problems as p
    join dbo.calendar as c
        on c.CalendarDate between p.ProblemNow and p.Now
            and c.BusinessDay = 1
group by p.ProblemNow
        ,p.Now
```

Comment: Thank you iamdave. I was able to do replicate easily. I didn't realize I could put criteria in the on clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this without a cursor. Should only require a single insert..select statement.

I assume your "businessday" column is just a bit or flag-type field that is 1 if the date is a business day and 0 if not? If so, this should work (or something close to it if I'm not understanding your environment properly).:

```
insert ProblemsMoreThan7BusinessDays
(
    businessdays
,   number
)
select
    number
,   sum( businessday ) -- or count(*)
  from OpenProblemtimeDiffTable op
 inner join CalendarInformation ci on op.problem_new >= ci.[date]
   and op.[now] <= ci.[date]
   and ci.businessday = 1
 group by
    problem_number
```

I usually try to avoid the use of cursors and working with data in a procedural manner, especially if I can handle the task as above. Dont think of the data as 1000's of individual rows, but think of the data as only two sets of data. How do they relate?

Comment: Thank you Jamie. I wasn't able to replicate. I may need some more time to see what minor adjustments I need to make.